# How do I run this python script in java?

Tags: java, python

I want to use this script in my java app: https://github.com/jcapona/amazon-wishlist-scraper.

I've looked around and I tried executing the script like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        String s = null;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python C:\\\\Users\\\\Home\\\\work\\\\test.py");
         BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         while ((s=stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(s);
         }
    }
```

But I am not getting any output. What do I need to be able to run this specific script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
String command = "python /c start python path\to\script\script.py>";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                              InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      stdInput.close();
      while ((line = stdErr.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
      stdErr.close();
      p.waitFor();
      System.out.println("Done.");

p.destroy();
```

> Protip: Always copy your path from the file explorer tab

And since you are getting JSON response try [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) to parse it.

And if you want to work heavily on python using java, try exploring [Jython](https://www.jython.org/)

Comment: I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Should all of the files needed to run the file be in the same place?